# Viewport render and wire drawing mode problem in Blender Internal

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

Can't figure out, why objects with wire drawing do not participate in viewport render?
[image]

For example, it is very annoying to have a textured plane in front of camera in non-wire mode, but at the same time it is useless if you want to make a preview. How to deal with that?

Comment: Try to render with that drawing type in Blender-render

Comment: Didn't see a tag in question.. This seems to be a feature in Blender Internal, see https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/material-mode-maximum-draw-type.php. Object will be rendered in the F12 render but not in preview. Probably not much possible to change here

Comment: Well it seems so. Very sad that devs ditch BI leaving many holes in it.